# matlab: out of memory when concatenating sparse matrix with a vector

Tags: matlab, concatenation, sparse-matrix

I create a 3560 x 3560 sparse matrix, `A`. I then create two 1 X 3560  vectors, `S` and `T`.
When I run the following code (which concatenates S and T as rows in A and afterwards also as columns in A)

```
A=[A;S;T];
S=[S 0 0];
T=[T 0 0];
A=[A, S', T'];
```

The last line produces an `out of memory` error. 
I guess I am running out of memory since I have other variables stored, but it seems odd to me that adding two 3560 vectors would be the point in which I am exactly hitting my limit, so I think (or more accurately, wishfully think) that somehow the concatenations aren't done in a smart way...
Am I right or is there no hope (except for optimizing other pieces in my code)?

---

EDIT:
At the request of yoda, I am posting the full code. 
Basically what it does is get a N X N matrix of edge weights between the nodes of a graph, and adds two vectors that will act as a source and sink in a max flow computation.

```
nbr_sim(nbr_sim<0.8)=0;
A=sparse(size(nbr_sim,1)+2,size(nbr_sim,2)+2);
nelements=size(nbr_sim,1);
A(nbr_sim>0)=nbr_sim(nbr_sim>0);
clear nbr_sim;

S=abs([1 0 0]*n);
T=abs([0 1 0]*n);


A(1:nelements,end-1)=S';
A(1:nelements,end)=T';
A(end-1,1:nelements)=S;
A(end,1:nelements)=T;
```

Comment: You could do the concatenations on separate steps, and try.

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT:

As you say you have used considerable resources before this operation, it is entirely likely that you are close to the tipping point, when MATLAB gives you an out of memory error.

Remember that when you grow matrices on the fly either by concatenating or by indexing out of range, MATLAB creates a copy of the matrix in memory. So you're not just using up resources for that extra row, but for a copy of that entire matrix!

Here's an example on my machine where I try to grow a vector that's large enough to tip it over the memory limit.

```
clear
a=rand(2*10^9+1,1); %#create a large array
whos a
  Name               Size                  Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         2000000001x1             16000000008  double 

%#Now repeat the same, but by growing the array by one element
clear
a=rand(2*10^9,1);
a=[a;0];

??? Error using ==> vertcat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

So you see that although MATLAB can create a matrix with `2*10^9+1` elements in one go, when you try to create an array of the same size by append a single element to a `2*10^9` element vector, it runs out of memory.

---

If `S` and `T` are column vectors as you say, then `A=[A;S;T]` should give you an error:

> ??? Error using ==> vertcat
>   CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

So you must be doing something else. Concatenating will not change sparseness of the matrix i.e., it won't switch from sparse to full.

```
A=sprand(3560,3560,0.01); %#test matrices
S=rand(3560,1);
T=rand(3560,1);

B=[A,S,T]; %#join the columns
issparse(B)

ans =

     1
```

Moreover, a `3560x3560` matrix of doubles is only ~97 MB, which shouldn't give you an "out of memory" error...

Comment: sorry, fixed the misleading description. As I said in the question, the matrix itself is not enough to give me an out of memory error, but considering I have allocated quite a lot of resources before that, it does make sense (also remembering that matrices require contiguous blocks of memory and not just free memory). What seems less probable is that it happens while adding the one extra column to the matrix

Comment: @noam: If you know you're going to append those two columns, the simplest way is to preallocate a larger matrix. So when you create your sparse matrix `A`, make it a `3560x3562` matrix and when you need to insert `S` and `T`, you can do it as `A(:,[3561,3562])=[S,T];`

Comment: @yoda: OK, I used your suggestion, and what's happening now is very odd: Instead of the error being raised where I said it was raised before, it is now being raised at a line of code that was run before the whole block of code I showed here. The line executes `A(A<0)=0`, I guess that the error is from A<0 creating a boolean matrix, but how come this *earlier* piece of code didn't cause the error before

Comment: @noam: That is quite weird indeed, because the logical matrix created should also be sparse and a couple more zero columns in `A` shouldn't change anything. Is the error you get the same? i.e., out of memory? Could you perhaps post a little more of your code, especially the parts that are now giving you the error?

Comment: @yoda - added the full code. I still get an out of memory error, now at the first line of the posted code.

Comment: @noam: That is pretty weird, especially because nothing has been changed in the code including that line. It's only in the line after that you add the two columns as I suggested. Let's try nailing it down.. Could you try commenting out that line and just see if my suggestion works. Never mind that the answer in the end might be incorrect. Just run it to see if you get an out of memory elsewhere..

Comment: @yoda - I am not sure what you mean that nothing has been changed... Perhaps I missed something, but now A is preallocated so as to not create it two times.

Comment: @noam: What I meant to say was that till the pre-allocation (the second line in the code block above), you're using your old code (or did I get that wrong?). Yet you get the error in the first line above which means that the error is probably not due to preallocating `A`...

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with large matrix:

For full matrix, you'd better preallocate memory to avoid memory copy during extending.[see why](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html?searchHighlight=preallocating+memory)

The sparse case is more complicated, and can be even less efficiency than extending in full matrix, because the elements is stored in a compressed manner. Setting an "inner" entry may cause large memory overwrites([have a look here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/accessing-sparse-matrices.html#br7572b)).

So you'd better edit all the entries in advance and create with sparse() function, rather than call sparse() and then pad the data.